# Publishing profile security settings

Tags: security, beta-managed-package, tab

I have a custom tab.  I have decided by default a particular user profile should not be able to see this tab. So I go into set up / manage profiles / theprofile and make this tab hidden for the particular profile.

It works.

However, when I package this and install it the security settings are not updated for the profile.

I check the components for the package but there are none that indicate to me the new security settings have been published and installed. In fact, I can't find anything corresponding to them.

I check the available components http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_packageable_components.htm guide from force.com and it is not clear either.  It does say permission set is upgradeable but appears not to be.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

From the Docs:

Profile settings are applied to existing profiles in the subscriber's organization on install or upgrade. Only permissions related to new components created as part of the install or upgrade are applied.

[About Permission Sets and Profile Settings in Packages](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=distribution_perm_sets_profile_settings.htm)

Comment: I updated my answer with the link

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to figure it out but here's the solution:

### IN YOUR DE ORG:

1. Clone Standard Platform User profile (because is the one that has the Salesforce Platform license) and name it something meaningful like MyApp_Profile
2. Customize MyApp_Profile to match your desired access level for the users that will test or use your app
3. Add custom profile settings MyApp_Profile to the package
4. Go ahead an finish the package

### IN THE TEST_ORG (OR YOUR_CUSTOMER_ORG):

1. Pre-create a profile by cloning the Standard Platform User profile and name it something meaningful like MyApp_TestProfile
2. Assign MyApp_TestProfile to a user
3. Install the package and on Step 2 (Choose security level) of  the wizard you have to select the third option (Select security settings)
4. Under "Customize security" section make sure the MyApp_TestProfile (created on step 5) has the MyApp_Profile assigned (created on step 1)
5. Finish the Package installation
6. Log to the test or customer org with the user that has the MyApp_TestProfile assigned and choose your App from top right menu.
7. You're welcome!

I hope this solves your issue too!